# Add hours to workday in python

Tags: python, time, hour

I need the following script to compute the working hours from 9 am to 6 pm, so that if I add 5 hours it will be added from 9 am the next day.
Example: if it is now 5 pm and I add 5 hours and the working day ends at 6 pm, the output would be: 13 hours.
17 + 1 = 18 and
9 + 4 = 13 hs

So far the script computes hours regardless of the labor restriction.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
  
updated = ( datetime.now() +
           timedelta( hours = 5 )).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
  
print( updated )
```

--22:12:00

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Are you expecting us to just write this for you or give you hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```py
workday_begin = time(9)
workday_end = time(18)

# compute workday length
workday_hours = datetime.combine(date.today(), workday_end) - datetime.combine(date.today(), workday_begin)

# this is timedelta from your example
duration_hours = timedelta(hours=17)

# ignore times longer than a workday
day_cnt = 0  # this could be used to know how many day we've skipped, not part of question tho
while duration_hours > workday_hours:
    day_cnt += 1
    duration_hours -= workday_hours

now = datetime.now()
# now = datetime(2021,12,10,11,25,16)
if workday_begin < now.time() < workday_end:
    # now is in work-hours
    if datetime.combine(date.today(), workday_end) - now < duration_hours:
        # duration would exceed work-hours, jumping to next day
        day_cnt += 1
        duration_hours -= (datetime.combine(date.today(), workday_end) - now)
        updated = datetime.combine(date.today(), workday_begin) + duration_hours
    else:
        # everything is fine, just add hours
        updated = now + duration_hours
else:
    # now is not in work-hours. Add remaining duration to workday begin
    updated = datetime.combine(date.today(), workday_begin) + duration_hours

# keep just a time part
updated = updated.time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

print( updated )
```

I hope I understood your question.

Comment: Excellent work! You got it perfectly :D